# Seismic activity in the UK

Tags: plate-tectonics, earthquakes

On 8th September 2020 there was a [magnitude 3.9 earthquake here in the UK](https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/us7000bjlf/region-info) at [51.817°N 0.665°W](https://www.google.com/maps/place/51%C2%B049%2701.2%22N+0%C2%B039%2754.0%22W/@51.817,-0.7350432,12z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d51.817!4d-0.665) which is approx. 10km/6.2miles east of Aylesbury or roughly 50km/31miles east of Oxford.

This got me wondering how the epicentre could be right there when there are no tectonic plate edges there.  The UK sits within the Eurasian Tectonic Plate, not on the edge.

[image: The Eurasian Tectonic Plate]
<sub>Image courtesy of [WikiMedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:EurasianPlate.png) and under creative commons licence [CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)</sub>

So how could an earthquake occur in the UK and what kind of earthquake would it be? The depth of this quake was at [10km ± 2km](https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/us7000bjlf/origin/detail) so was it a [subduction quake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subduction)? If so the subduction plate boundary would be huge.

Comment: it is not uncommon with smaller earthquakes in this area in north europe and scandinavia,most are caused by isostatic rebound after the ice age.https://www.lifeinnorway.net/earthquakes-in-norway/